# Remove Duplicate characters

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, data-structures

The problem i am facing is :

> Given a string which contains only lowercase letters, remove duplicate letters so that every letter appear once and only once. You must make sure your result is the `smallest in lexicographical` order among all possible results.

**Example**
Given "bcabc"
Return "abc"

Given "cbacdcbc"
Return "acdb"

I thought of few approaches but still not able to crack the problem. The link to the problem is [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicate-letters/#/description)

**I dont want any code in solution but the approach i can take to solve the question only. Thanks in advance.**

**Update: Will add the approach i took(which is wrong/incomplete by the way)**

> Will save the last positions of each character in the string in some data structure. after that will start processing the characters in the ascending order of their last position.Eg : in first iteration the character with the minimum last position is processed. i thought i will iterate through the string up untill last position of the character i am processsing and will remove few characters on some conditions(like if the character while looping is less than the character with min Last position and other was same only but greater than it). but all were failing only.

Comment: Please explain the approaches you've thought of and what was wrong with them.

Comment: one approach was : will save the last positions of each character in some data structure. then will take the character which is having the minimum last position. Then i will loop till that position, and will eliminate some characters based on some condition. i tried few conditions(like if the character while looping is less than the character with min Last position and other was same only but greater than it). but all were failing only

Comment: Please place those explanations in the question.

Comment: i didnt want to give a wrong approach in the question, thats why didnt put it there.

Comment: Describing your current approach and what's wrong with it is intrinsic to StackOverflow :-). Not only does it give us a starting framework, but it gives us an insight into your thought process and can help us show you your misunderstanding. Also it demonstrates that you've made an effort to solve it yourself and you're not just asking for a handout.

Comment: yeah sure. will do it then now. thanks. and sorry . i am a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

### Algorithm

Your approach sounds like it is almost there.

The first steps sound good:

> Save the last positions of each character in the string in some data structure. after that will start processing the characters in the ascending order of their last position.
>
> in first iteration the character with the minimum last position is processed.

In your example "cbacdcbc", the minimum last position is 3, the location of the a.

The first letter of the string will be equal to the minimum character in these first 3 positions (in this case, the letter a).

Now you can repeat this procedure starting from the letter after the one you just picked.  So in this case "cdcbc".  The only difference is that you can now ignore the last positions for any letters that you have picked as you are not allowed to pick these again.

### Explanation

Consider choosing the first letter of the output.  We want to know the smallest it can be.  To make it small we need to delete characters before it in the string, but we must not delete a character if it is the last occurrence (because this will make it impossible to satisfy the constraints).

Therefore we know that we can safely delete characters up to the minimum last position, and we wish to know what is the smallest the first character of the output can be, therefore we should just pick the smallest in the allowed range.  (If there is are more than one of the smallest, then pick the earliest.)

Comment: Can you please explain how you can tell that the character minimum than the character at min. Last position will be there in the answer. I am not able to understand how we can tell that. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added some more explanation, it may also help if you try to construct a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Set type depending on the language u are using.
Something like a SortedSet would probably solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the hash table

lets say this is the string "cbacdcbc"

create a array of length 26, fill all 0 in the array.
Now iterate throght the string and place each character in array at index value of characters ascii value, sort out the array and you done with the problem.

say int a[26];

a['c']= valuse of c here;

Comment: the answer for the string **cbacdcbc** is **acdb** but your algorithm will give **abcd**

Comment: can you bit explain how acdb would be the result.

Okay got it, its a stack problem, think that way, any way what is the time complexity you need for this code?

Comment: first of all you will have to some preprocessing before putting the character in the array. like **a['c' - 65] = 'c'**. i hope u get this step. after doing this for the whole string u will have in some places values greater than 0. now you are sorting that array(that also u cant do directly as they there are elements not present in the string). you will always get a < b < c.. therefore your algorithm will give the unique characters but not the correct answer

Comment: I think seeing the lexicographical you are getting confused. just go through the question and the example once again. you will get it

Comment: Yeah, i didnt wrote that preprocessing coz, its common thought you must be aware of that, n yeah with my algo ans would not be correct